# Is there any way to bind name instead of id in table by comparing with another array

Tags: reactjs

I am working on react js table and I am stuck. Is it possible to bind name instead of id to `table` by comparing it with another array?

Example:

```
this.state={
table :[{countryId:1,cityId:1}],
countries:[{id:1,name:"india"},{id:2,name:"USA"}],
cities:[{id:1,name:"hyd"},{id:2,name:"chennai"}]
}
    <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>country Name</td>
       <td>city Name</td>
      </tr>
     
    {this.state.table.map((item)=>{
    return(
    <tr>
       <td>{item.countryId}</td> //here iam getting id of country and need to compare and return the country name from another array
       <td>{item.cityId}</td> //same like above,need to compare with cities array and return city name for corresponding city id
     </tr>
    )}
    
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example (by editing your question) of your state and the other array, and explain what you need exchanged?

Comment: you can use object `countryObject[item.countryId]`  or an array `countryArray.find(c => c.id === item.countryId)`

Comment: updated please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.find` on `cities` and `countries` arrays to find the one you need based on current `item` properties and then render their names.

```js
this.state={
table :[{countryId:1,cityId:1}],
countries:[{id:1,name:"india"},{id:2,name:"USA"}],
cities:[{id:1,name:"hyd"},{id:2,name:"chennai"}]
}
    <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>country Name</td>
       <td>city Name</td>
      </tr>
     
    {this.state.table.map((item)=>{
      const country = this.state.countries.find(c => c.id === item.countryId);
      const city = this.state.cities.find(c => c.id === item.cityId);
      return(
        <tr>
         <td>{country.name}</td>
         <td>{city.name}</td>
       </tr>
      )}
    </tbody>
```